# Array from the core data is not saved in iPhone but saving in simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Something weird
I m storing  Array in a attribute on core data,

When I run the application on the iPhone(iphone 6s) that shows that   everything worked good.
**But when I close the app, which will not run in the background,

and open the app again , the array is empty !

I do the same thing on the simulator in xcode and everything works   great!**

What is the reason ?

I keep the array in such a attribute type - binary data

And this code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.arr = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[_obj2 valueForKey :@"arrayDataEvent"]];

    if(self.arr==nil)
    {
        self.arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
}
-(void)save//button
{

    if (self.obj2)//obj2 is a specific NSManagedobject from another controller table view
    {
        NSString*str=[NSString stringWithString:_textView.text];
            [self.arr addObject:str];

        NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.arr];
        [_obj2 setValue:data forKey:@"arrayDataEvent"];

        NSMutableArray*arr2 = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[_obj2 valueForKey :@"arrayDataEvent"]];

        NSLog(@"  arr = %@",arr2 );
    }
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: How are you actually creating this obj2. It might be created in the context but never saved in CoreData. Looks like you only have this object alive in the context. Once you close the app and new context is created you are loosing your object.

Comment: i move the original manage object whit segue , this is my way to get info to more view controller. But now I understand, but how to update the object from the vc else?

Answer (score 0):

Core Data is not a suitable framework to store arrays on the fly. IMO, you should go with one of two options:

1. You either make a proper data model (object graph) with a to-many relationship to model the array elements;
2. or you use the egregiously simpler `NSUserDefaults` which seems to match your requirements much better.

As to your specific question: you are apparently not **saving** your managed object context. The data is not written to the store and will not be available when you restart the app.

```
do { try context.save() } catch { print("Couln't save.") }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but it does not help me much.
No matter how I tried to work with the relationship I could not (really ashamed)
And I keep a lot of strings so that Userdefuled, will occupy a lot of memory.
I took a chance, and I save in the core data Array, and the truth? It works very quickly.

Comment: I am sorry this does not help you. It should if you just try out the last piece of advice (saving). -- What you are trying to do is really not that difficult, and you should try to learn these basic techniques. As for `NSUserDefaults` and memory: you are mistaken! Reading the array from Core Data uses exactly the same amount of memory for the data, maybe more. As for speed: `NSUserDefaults` is just as fast, and it is thread-safe and there is no framework overhead and you write much less code.